# Javascript - React Native. Child Component (Dynamic List) does not render when Render() function is called

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm working on an app and one of its parts consists on a list of players. Each item on the list contains the name of the player, the points that he/she has and a IOS stepper to change de points. 
[See the app screen I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhxmU.png)

Every time I modify the points of a player using the IOS stepper the state of the App changes according to that value. However, the text containing the points of the player does not get modified. The render function is called and the state of the app has not mutated so the text component should change as well. I have found out that when the render function is called it "jumps" over the List component so this isn't rendered and renderRow function isn't called.

The text only shows the current player's points when I change to the second tab of the TabBar and then I go back to the first one. In that case the List component gets rendered.

I think this is a really weird situation and I have tried everything to solve it but I haven't found any solution. I leave the code below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {Container, Content, Picker, Header, Title, Subtitle, Button, Left, 
Right, Body, Icon, List, ListItem, Input } from 'native-base';
import {ferLlistaRondes, canviDeRonda, crearObjectePPR, modificarPunts, 
canviarColorPunts} from '../actions';
import SimpleStepper from 'react-native-simple-stepper';

class SetPoints extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.modifyPunts = this.modifyPunts.bind(this);
    this.changeDeRonda = this.changeDeRonda.bind(this);
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this)
  }

  modifyPunts(value, nomJugador) {
    this.props.modificarPunts(nomJugador, value, this.props.currentRound)
  }

  changeDeRonda(novaRonda) {
    this.props.canviDeRonda(novaRonda);
  }

  renderRow(data) {
    return(
      <ListItem icon>
        <Left>
            <Icon name = 'md-person'/>
        </Left>
        <Body>
           <Text>{data}</Text>
        </Body>
        <Right>
          <View style = {styles.pointsViewStyle}>
            <Text>
              {this.props.ObjRondaJugadorPunts[data][this.props.currentRound-1]}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <SimpleStepper
            initialValue = {this.props.ObjRondaJugadorPunts[data]
[this.props.currentRound-1]}
            stepValue = {5}
            minimumValue = {-100}
            maximumValue = {100}
            padding = {2}
            valueChanged = {(value) => this.modifyPunts(value,data)}
          />
        </Right>
      </ListItem>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <List
            dataArray={this.props.llistaFinal}
            renderRow={(data) => this.renderRow(data)}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    )
  }

}

const styles = {
  subtitleStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontFamily:'Noteworthy'
  },
  pointsViewStyle: {
    paddingRight:10
  },
  pickerViewStyle: {
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    numJugadors: state.appRender.jugadors,
    numRondes: state.appRender.rondes,
    llistaFinal: state.appRender.llistaNomsAcabada,
    llistaRondes: state.appRender.llistaRondes,
    currentRound: state.appRender.currentRound,
    ObjRondaJugadorPunts: state.appRender.roundPlayerPointsObj,
    colorPunts: state.appRender.colorPunts
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {ferLlistaRondes, crearObjectePPR, 
canviDeRonda, modificarPunts, canviarColorPunts})(SetPoints);
```

I hope you can help me fix that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it to solve the problem. Native Base dynamic list component is based on react native list view. List view only rerenders if its prop dataSource changes. As I could not change native base dynamic list dataSource prop (because it does not directly have this prop, it has a similar one called dataArray which does not produce a rerender when it changes), I ended up using a react native list view component. Therefore I only needed to change the data source prop every time I want it to rerender, so items inside every row were refreshing as well as spected.

For what I read in some posts, native base is working on a solution in order to offer the possibility to control the rerender of its list component (like react native offers through dataSource prop).